# How to calculate average of each student in C++ using multi dimentional array?

Tags: c++

I want to calculate the average of each student using c++ and multi-dimensional array. In my code below it will display the grade of the each student in each subject. How can I list all the scores and at the end will display the average of each student?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 4;

void fillScores(int[ROWS][COLS]);
void printScores(int[ROWS][COLS]);

int main()
{
    int scores[ROWS][COLS];

    fillScores(scores);
    printScores(scores);

    return 0;
}

void fillScores(int newScores[ROWS][COLS]){
    int score;

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
        cout << "Enter scores for exam " << (i + 1) << ": ";

        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
            cin >> score;
            newScores[i][j] = score;
        }
    }
}

void printScores(int newScores[ROWS][COLS]){
    for(int i = 0; i < COLS; i++){
        cout << "Student " << (i + 1) << " Scores: ";

        for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){
            cout << newScores[j][i] << " Average Score: " << (newScores[j][i]/COLS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should at least attempt to do the assignment and tell us what you're having trouble with.  All you have so far is filling and printing.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? Can you do this calculation by hand on a piece of paper? Where did you get stuck between paper and code? It's not clear to me what you're problem is.

Comment: @scohe001 I dont know where to put the calculation for the average

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am having trouble where to put the calculations for average in order to display it

Comment: @Lawrence Agulto Why is the first loop in  printScores that is the loop for(int i = 0; i < COLS; i++){ calculated by columns?

Comment: @scohe001 please see my updated code

Comment: I don't really understand what problems you're having.  It is obvious that the calculation has to come after you read the scores in and before you print out the final values, right?  So what would you think is the place to put that code?  Wouldn't it be between the lines in `main` after you've read the names in and before you print out the values?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie How do I get the average the correct way please show me I am just a begginer

Comment: You add up the scores and divide by the number of scores.  Why haven't you written a smaller program, like `int main() { int numbers[] = {34, 45, 23}; }` and see how to get the average of those numbers in the array?  That is essentially what you need to do.

Comment: Please describe how you would calculate the average yourself, using pen and paper. Which values are you using? Where would you find them in your array? Can you print just all the relevant values? Can you sum them up? Can you count them or somehow know how many there are? Can you calculate a quotient and store it in an appropriate variable? Can you output that variable? Where in these steps do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print it (without storing it in a variable) you can do it when you are printing:

```
void printScores(int newScores[ROWS][COLS]){
    for(int i = 0; i < COLS; i++){
        cout << "Student " << (i + 1) << " Scores: ";

        float examsum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
            examsum += newScores[j][i];
            cout << newScores[j][i] << " ";
        }

        cout << "Average: " << examsum/ROWS << endl;
    }
}
```